# SQL: Can WHERE Statement filter out specific groups for GROUP BY Statement

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm still new to SQL and playing inside a SQLite3 test database.  I tried digging online for this answer but could not find an answer.  I cannot get my test query to exclude certain groups using **WHERE** before a **GROUP BY** Statement.

**Here is my query:**

```
SELECT USER_ID, SESSION_ID, MAX(SESSION_DURATION), MAX(TIME_STAMP)
FROM table
WHERE SESSION_ID <> 0
GROUP BY USER_ID, SESSION_ID
```

Basically in my database, there are rows where session ID is 0.  I would like to exclude those rows before applying trying to group them up.  However, the result returns groups with session id = 0

Thanks for the help!

**UPDATE 1**

Similar to sqlfiddle (Below), while creating a simple test database the query actually works.

I am actually using Python and the SQLite3 library to import a 15 K row CSV file into the database and running the query.  Obviously something is breaking cause of my import code since my Test table that is working.  I will keep you all posted on what I discover.  Thank you everyone for your help.

**UPDATE 2**

I have now tested my import code with the same test table and the query works filtering out group 0 using this very simple CSV file.  Unfortunately, I cannot post multiple links else I will post my simple test CSV

However, with my 15 K CSV file, it does not work.   Here is a link to the 15 K file
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69835430/sql_session_data.csv

Is there any specific edge case I missed?

**UPDATE 3 - FINAL ANSWER**

Thanks to CL's answer below about a string value in my INTEGER column.  I dug around about the SQLite3 module I was using.

I was using the sqlite3.dictreader and passing in the default read value.  I fixed this by adding a *== ''* check when parsing my CSV file before putting the data into the DB.

Thank you for everyone's help!

Comment: i'll try to create a smaller test db to run this on. Sorry can't pass out the actual one.  I'm also using SQLite Expert Personal 3.5.6 to run my query and management if that makes a difference?

Comment: I created SESSION_ID as an Integer.  Each User is assigned a unique Int based Session ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
> SELECT 0 <> 0;
0
> SELECT '0' <> 0;
1
```

You have string values in your database.
Fix them:

```sql
UPDATE MyTable
SET Session_ID = CAST(Session_ID AS INTEGER);
```

Comment: Thanks CL! That indeed was the problem.  Im looking at my import code to handle those specific cases and seeing why the SQLite3 Writer is not handling that case.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods works for me (as expected) with a simple dataset.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d6736/1)

```
create table tbl (user_id int, session_id int, duration int);
insert into tbl values (1,0,10);
insert into tbl values (1,1,2);
insert into tbl values (2,1,1);
insert into tbl values (3,2,1);
insert into tbl values (4,2,5);

SELECT USER_ID, SESSION_ID, MAX(duration), count(1)
FROM tbl
WHERE SESSION_ID <> 0
GROUP BY USER_ID, SESSION_ID
```